# Laravel API Rest

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to hit my destroy API below
[image]

Gives me an error

> "Call to a member function delete() on null"

Please help

my route definition in web.php is `

> Route::resource('posts', 'postcarController');
>    my controller code is as below
>
> ```
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> use App\PostModell;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
>
> class postcarController extends Controller
> {
>    public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->middleware('auth');
>     }
>
>    public function destroy($id)
>     {
>         //PostModel::where('id',$id)->delete();
>          $post = PostModel::find($id);
>         if($post!=null){
>           $post->delete();
>          return response()->json([
>             'message' => 'book deleted',
>         ], 200);
>    }
>
>    }
> }
> ```

`I changed my url to http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/3 appropriately and get error

> The page has expired due to inactivity.
>
> Please refresh and try again.

Comment: probably you don't have any record with that id, check your db record

Comment: I have 50 records from 1 yo 50

Comment: try `dd($post)` and see if there any records exists

Comment: yes i have 50 records

Comment: could you please share what `dd($post)` gives

Comment: {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Mathew Dickinson",
        "body": "Consequatur eos excepturi voluptatum quasi.",
        "color": "West Ottilieview",
        "model_code": "Minnesota",
        "drive_type": "Alabama",
        "fuel": "Hodkiewicz-Beer",
        "engine_type": "http://smith.org/",
        "CC": "442.962.0085 x99985",
        "production_year": "1986",
        "condition": "North Carolina",
        "created_at": "2018-01-29 05:20:22",
        "updated_at": "2018-01-29 05:20:22"
    },

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `fetching` the record and then `deleting` it, you could do it with one line like -

```
PostModel::where('id',$id)->delete();
```

Or you could check if record exists with that id or not and than delete it -

```
$post = PostModel::find($id);
if($post!=null){
  $post->delete();
  return //your new response;
}

return //response with message that no record exits
```

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI see my updated answer, it may help you

Comment: still the same error persist   "Call to a member function delete() on null"

Comment: please share your controller code with route definition and did you really updated your code with my code as there is no way it could give such error

Comment: This is my route definition in web.php  Route::resource('posts', 'postcarController');

Comment: please add this to your question with `postcarController` code

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI you are hitting `/cars/{id}` and you are changing on `posts/{id}`, how you expect to work?? change your code on corresponding implementation of `/cars/{id}` url.

Comment: changed my url to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/3 and still get an error  The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#configuration see this and change your session driver to file